# Does jquery or javascript have a function like (onEnterFrame in flash)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, flash

I came from as2 and as3 background. I would like to know whether jquery, javascript or ajax provide onEnterFrame function in flash?

My Goal is to auto align **runtime** my #div1 (left) when the user resize the browser or zoom in/out

```
 __________________________________
|     |                    |      | 
|     |     #banner div    |      |           
|     |                    |      |
|     |____________________|      |
|     |      div 1         |      |      
|     |                    |      |
-----------------------------------

#div1 {
position: absolute;
left: some random number based on the browser width;
top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: When you say "random", do you really mean a random number - as in, every time the user visits your page the left position is different from the last time, or do you mean an arbitrary number - as in, whatever you decide?

Answer (score 1):

First off, JavaScript doesn't have the concept of a timeline, so generally, any timeline-related events such as 'onEnterFrame' are not available to you. Creating applications in html/css/js is more like creating applications in Flex rather than Flash.

Now to provide a specific solution for your problem, you can try something like:

```
var box = document.getElementById("div1");
var box_style = box.style;

window.onresize = function(e){
    box_style.left = Math.random() * 200 + "px"; // your max value instead of 200
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/5grMx/

Answer (score 0):

no, but you can set a timer in javascript and that is your onEnterFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most similar function to `onEnterFrame` is `requestAnimationFrame`(1).
And it is exactly called before a frame rendered.
However it is called only once, if you want it to be called repeatedly.
You need to request new callback again in the callback.

But if you want it to fired only before window resize, you can use `window.onresize` event(2).

And if you just want to use static value like `50 % of its base container's width + 20 px`.
You can just use css to do that, css3 has a length type called `calc()`(3).
Allow you to calculate length based on its base container.

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.requestAnimationFrame
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc